# Sliding Drawer From Top

Tags: android

I'm trying to get a sliding drawer to pull down from the top in my application, but I can't figure out a way to do it. Any help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The built in sliding drawer is not that flexible, your best bet is to extend it and modify its behavior, or take a look at this http://code.google.com/p/android-misc-widgets/

Comment: Ironically, I've already tried using that one, but it uses an old SDK function with R.styleable which is deprecated now, so I don't know how to get it working. Are there any examples with this actually working that are with a newer SDK version?

Comment: Alright, I got it working. I had to use built in methods for grabbing the attributes.

Comment: I used this sample with making no changes in 2.1, 2.2, and now 2.3 sdks

Answer (score 0):

I had to do the same for one of my projects and I ended up writing my own widget for this. I called it **SlidingTray** is now part of my open source **Aniqroid** library. It allows sliding from all four corners and feel free to modify the code as your like.

http://aniqroid.sileria.com/doc/api/  (Look for download options to get it)

(Disclosure: I am the maintainer of the project.)

Comment: Posting the same answer multiple times is not the best way to make this site better. If you find that the same question has been asked multiple times, please flag them as duplicates using the "flag" link just below the question. This will allow moderators to merge the questions and make the end result better.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a complete replacement for SlidingDrawer.  It can slide from any direction and I find that it greatly outperforms the original.  http://www.github.com/kedzie/DraggableDrawers