# SlidingDrawer above other views

Tags: java, android, slidingdrawer

how do i place a slidingdrawer above another view so i doesnt come out from the bottom of the screen, but from the top of another view ?

my code so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:background="@drawable/splash">
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                  android:background="#000000">
     <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                   android:orientation="vertical"
                   android:background="@drawable/splash">
        <Button android:id="@id/content"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="I'm in here!"/>
     </LinearLayout>
     <SlidingDrawer android:id="@+id/drawer"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:handle="@+id/handle"
                    android:content="@+id/content">
        <ImageView android:id="@id/handle"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:src="@drawable/categories_bar_flipped"/>
        <Button android:id="@id/content"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="I'm in here!"/>
     </SlidingDrawer>
  </RelativeLayout>
  <EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

problem is that the EditText disappeares and the sliderhandle is dokked at bottom of screen instead of at top of the EditText

Comment: I believe the sliding drawer has to be docked against an edge of the screen.  If you need some different behavior, you may need to extend SlidingDrawer and create a custom view.

Answer (score 1):

Use a framelayout which will stack views on top of each other based on the order of the childs. That should make the drawer appear on top.

Answer (score 0):

Check some answers:

- [Sliding Drawer From Top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247968/sliding-drawer-from-top)
- [How to make an Android SlidingDrawer slide out from the left?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137350/how-to-make-an-android-slidingdrawer-slide-out-from-the-left)
- http://code.google.com/p/aniqroid - Library to do that

It has code examples of how to do that.